# Using .ENV value in NodeJS, Required Key Error in Procfile Definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreman, env

I am trying to use the foreman package to see if the way I setup my `.env` file will work with use in one of my JS files, but when I run `nf start server.js` I receive the following warnings and then the server never starts. I thought it was related to not calling the variable in the server.js file, but that didn't change anything

```
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[WARN] No Procfile Found
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
[OKAY] Trimming display Output to 55 Columns
[WARN] Required Key 'server.js' Does Not Exist in Procfile Definition
```

Here is how I'm using my `.env` file:

.env

```
DB_CONFIGURATION=mongodb://<user>:<pw>.mongolab.com:6383219/db-name
```

blogDB.js:

```
var DB_CONFIG = process.env.DB_CONFIGURATION;

module.exports = {
    url : DB_CONFIG;
}
```

server.js (Where I'm calling the blogDB file)

```
//Load express
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the router
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // configure app to use bodyParser()
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true})); // get data from a POST method
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());


var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set the port


var blogDB = require('./config/blogDB.js');
mongoose.connect(blogDB.url);

require('./config/passport.js')(passport);


app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set ejs as the view engine

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the public directory

app.use(session({ secret: 'thisisatest' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());



var routes = require('./app/routes');

app.use(routes); // use routes.js


app.listen(port);
console.log('magic is happening on port' + port);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Foreman you need to create a file named `Procfile` in the root of your project -- this file tells foreman how to run your project.

In this file, you might want to put a line like this:

```
web: node server.js
```

Or, whatever command is used to 'start' your web service. Then, if you run `foreman start` from the command line, foreman will parse the Procfile, then run that command for you (`node server.js`).